# How can use NDK JNI to access static C++ Library

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I want to use a static library not compiled with NDK within a C++ class that is compiled usinG NDK.  How can this be done.  So for example I want to use test.lib function where test.lib is some gnu compiled static C++ library (not compiled by using NDK, its third party so no source avail).

Comment: For which target machine the library was compiled? Is it armeabi? Try readelf -h on your lib.

Comment: ran the command under cygwin got nothing back.

Answer (score 0):

Then is it windows static library (which you used to link with windows executables)? If yes then you cannot use it on android because of two things: 
1. lib has non-elf file format (elf is used by android)
2. lib is compiled for x86 (amd64) architecture (android devices have arm processor in most cases).